# Strange error with Process.sleep in a supervised Task

Tags: elixir

This simple code is not working

```
defmodule ElixirCluster do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(Task, [fn ->
        IO.puts("Hello")
        Process.sleep(1000) #:timer.sleep(1000)
        IO.puts("World")
      end])
    ]
    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: ElixirCluster.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

it only prints `Hello` and then the program stop, it doesn't even retry, and never prints `World`. I  dont have a clue what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely ran the application using just `mix`, which stops the VM soon after starting the application, and since you have a 1 second sleep after printing `Hello`, you never execute printing `World`. If you run the application with `--no-halt`, you'll see `World` printed after `Hello` and the process being restarted as soon as it ends:

```
$ mix run --no-halt
Hello
World
Hello
World
Hello
World
Hello
World

07:32:25.670 [info]  Application elixir_cluster exited: shutdown
```

Note that the Supervisor gives up restarting the worker for the 4th time and kills itself as the [default opts only restarts the worker 3 times within 5 seconds before giving up](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.Spec.html#supervise/2):

> `:max_restarts` - the maximum amount of restarts allowed in a time frame. Defaults to `3`.
>   `:max_seconds` - the time frame in which `:max_restarts` applies. Defaults to `5`.

while your Task requires about 5 restarts every 5 seconds.

You can change that if you want:

```
opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: ElixirCluster.Supervisor, max_restarts: 6, max_seconds: 5]
```

Now `mix run --no-halt` will continue printing forever.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out but spent more time than necessary.